# How do I delete my StackExchange account?

Tags: discussion

I created an account here to merely post a comment pointing out the error of logic in an accepted answer, and thereby show that the accepted answer is, in actuality, incorrect. Since I do not have the time nor interesting in 'earning' the right to comment, I want my account and all information related to me deleted. Thus my question, how do I delete my StackExchange account and all information related to me?

Comment: Duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account... and seriously, have you tried using a search engine?

Comment: [Delete your account like this.](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account)

Answer (score 5):

Delete your account by the method posted in [the help section](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account) located in the upper right hand side of your page.